# Making same android activity class as a service ondestroy

Tags: android, android-service

This is an application that measures the sound intensity and in accordance with that measured value it sets the seek bar and in turn it adjusts the ringer volume in accordance with the seek bar automatically.

I want to run this application in foreground as well as in background
 when user destroys it. Because the user will definately be needing
 the app even after he quits it. I have read the documentation of
 creating a service but the problem is i want full code same as
 activity to be run in the background after the app destroyal..So any
 help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 package com.example.soundmeter;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.media.MediaRecorder;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.media.AudioManager;
 import android.view.KeyEvent;
 import android.widget.SeekBar;
 import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

 import com.example.soundmeter.R;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 //public static boolean isService = false;     
 TextView mStatusView;
 MediaRecorder mRecorder;
 Thread runner;
 private static double mEMA = 0.0;
 static final private double EMA_FILTER = 0.6;

 //a variable to store the seek bar from the XML file  
 public SeekBar volumeBar; 

 //an AudioManager object, to change the volume settings  
 private AudioManager amanager; 

 final Runnable updater = new Runnable(){

     public void run(){          
         updateTv();
     };
 };
 final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);


     //startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,BackGroundService.class));
     if (runner == null)
     { 
         runner = new Thread(){
             public void run()
             {
                 while (runner != null)
                 {
                    volumeChanger();
                     try
                     {
                         Thread.sleep(5000);
                         Log.i("Noise", "Tock");

                     } catch (InterruptedException e) { };

                     mHandler.post(updater);
                 }
             }
         };

         runner.start();
         Log.d("Noise", "start runner()");
     }
 }

 public void onResume()

 {
     super.onResume();
     startRecorder();
 }

 public void onPause()
 {
    super.onResume();
    startRecorder();
     //super.onPause();
     //super.stopRecorder();
 }

 /*@Override
 public void onBackPressed()
 {
    super.onResume();
    startRecorder();
 }*/

 public void startRecorder(){
     if (mRecorder == null)
     {
         mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
         mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
         mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
         mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
         mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null"); 
         try
         {           
             mRecorder.prepare();
         }catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
             android.util.Log.e("[Monkey]", "IOException: " + 
 android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(ioe));

         }catch (java.lang.SecurityException e) {
             android.util.Log.e("[Monkey]", "SecurityException: " +   
 android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(e));
         }
         try
         {           
             mRecorder.start();
         }catch (java.lang.SecurityException e) {
             android.util.Log.e("[Monkey]", "SecurityException: " +    
 android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(e));
         }

         //mEMA = 0.0;
     }

 }
 /*public void stopRecorder() {
     if (mRecorder != null) {
         mRecorder.stop();       
         mRecorder.release();
         mRecorder = null;
     }
 }*/

 public void updateTv(){

    double amp=getAmplitudeEMA();
     mStatusView.setText(Double.toString((amp)) + " dB");
 }

 public double soundDb(double ampl){
     double intensity=20 * Math.log10(getAmplitudeEMA() / ampl);
    return  intensity;
 }
 public double getAmplitude() {
     if (mRecorder != null)
         return  (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude());
     else
         return 0;

 }
 public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
     double amp =  getAmplitude();
     mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
     return mEMA;
 }

 public void volumeChanger()
 {
     volumeBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb_volumebar);

      //get the audio manager
      amanager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

      //seek bar settings//
      //sets the range between 0 and the max volume
      volumeBar.setMax(amanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
      //set the seek bar progress to 1
      //volumeBar.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);

      //sets the progress of the seek bar based on the system's volume
     // volumeBar.setProgress(500);

      if(mEMA<(double)800.00)
      {
         volumeBar.setProgress((int)amanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)/5);
      }

      else if(mEMA<(double)15000.00)
      {
         volumeBar.setProgress((int)amanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)*2/5);
      }

      else if(mEMA<25000.00)
      {
         volumeBar.setProgress((int)amanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)*3/5);
      }

      else if(mEMA<50000.00)
      {
         volumeBar.setProgress((int)amanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)*4/5);
      }

      else
      {
         volumeBar.setProgress((int)amanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
      }

      //register OnSeekBarChangeListener, so that the seek bar can change the volume
        volumeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
            {
                int index=volumeBar.getProgress();
                //change the volume, displaying a toast message containing the current volume and playing a feedback sound
                amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, index, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            }
        });
  }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        //if one of the volume keys were pressed
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
        {
            //change the seek bar progress indicator position
            volumeBar.setProgress(amanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
        }

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
        }

        //propagate the key event
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out another way of doing it.
A broadcast Receiver can be used in the main activity in syncronization with a broadcast service.

Answer (score 0):

Have the measurement code always listen on the service and let it update shared preferences.

Then all the activity needs to do is listen to changes on shared preferences and update the UI accordingly.

You can obviously use any number of mechanisms to allow the activity respond to the services changes, but I think listening for shared preference changes is probably easiest to start with.

```
listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    //update ui if your key was updated
  }
};

prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```